# Switching forms with a Drop-Down menu?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, drop-down-menu, navigation

So I'm not very good at C# but I thought a pretty cool idea would be to learn form switching with a drop-down. I have the following code that does switch forms but the variables are declared at the wrong parts or something since it switches to the wrong form even if they are specified. "Builder" opens the "Pumper" tab even when Builder is the selected index of the drop down.

```
    if
          (bunifuDropdown1.selectedIndex.ToString() == "Builder") ;
        Decoder f4 = new Decoder();
        Pumper f3 = new Pumper();
        Builder f2 = new Builder();
        f2.Show();
        f3.Hide();
        f4.Hide();
        this.Hide();


        if
          (bunifuDropdown1.selectedIndex.ToString() == "Pumper") ;
        f3.Show();
        f2.Hide();
        f4.Hide();
        this.Hide();
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The code you shared does not compile. Can you share a working code?

Comment: `bunifuDropdown1.selectedIndex` returns the item number which is selected in the drop-down list. you should use  `bunifuDropdown1.selectedItem`

Comment: You need to use brackets `{....}` around multi-line `if` blocks. And you need to remove the `;` on the `if` condition. As written, you could completely remove the `if` statements and not change the behavior of the code.

Comment: Thanks guys I'm going to check this out and Chetan, this isn't the whole project code but if you want it I can show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I roughly understood what you want, but to be honest, I am very lazy to write the wrong code that would achieve your goal ...
I'll tell you right away - you have a bad idea :). Because you will include the navigation menu in each independent form and you need to think about how to come up with a common data object (such as a class) that will be simultaneously available in all forms and fill in the data in the executing list (maybe it will help you "ApplicationContext Class" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2).

The optimal way, for example, is to make a form, place the "ComboBox" (p.s. and why do you need a third-party graphics framework? ...) object (add the necessary elements), add the "Panel" (or "TabControl") to the form, and link the display of the necessary blocks to the "ComboBox" data change event .

For example:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "1")
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
        if ((string)comboBox1.SelectedItem == "2")
        {
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use third party frameworks for the UI of the other forms and I couldn't find a Drop-Down in normal Windows Forms. Edit: Thanks for the tip/help, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Em... isn't this a regular "ComboBox"? p.s. recommend https://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Core-Foundational-Programming/dp/1484257553